# Putting 1's in certain places

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix, sum, logical-operators

I have 2 matrices

```
  Matrix A = [7 3 5 2 8 4 1 6 9;
              5 2 6 1 4 3 9 7 8;
              9 1 4 5 2 6 3 6 7;
              4 8 1 6 3 7 2 9 5;
              6 1 7 2 8 4 5 9 3]

 Matrix B =  [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
              0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0;
              0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0;
              0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0;
              0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
```

Matrix A and B are already defined.

Here each column can't have more than 1 what i want to do is that if when i do sum for Matrix B if i found 0 in it i have to add 1's in the places of the zero's but in certain places. In each row the 1's have to be placed in certain groups. For example if a 1 is placed in column 1, then it can be placed as well in column 2 or 3 only. It can't be placed anywhere else. If in another row it is placed in column 5, then it can be placed in column 4 or 6 only and so on. It's like group of 3. Each 3 columns are together.

To be more clear:

Here the sum of matrix B is `[1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1]`. The zeros here are placed in column 5 and 7 and i want to add 1 putting in mind where the 1 is going to be placed in the matrix. So in this example the 1 of column 5 can only be placed in row 4 as the 1's in this row are placed in column 4 and 6. The 1 of column 7 can be placed in row 5 or row 3. If we have choice between 2 rows then the 1 will be placed in the placed of the higher number of Matrix A. 
The 1's have to be placed in groups; columns 1, 2 and 3 are together, columns 4,5 and 6 are together and columns 7, 8 and 9 are together. so if the 1 is placed in 1 column of the group then it can't be placed in any other place.

Let me simplify it if we have an array like this [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1] This array has 3 categories, columns 1,2 and 3 are 1st category, columns 4,5 and 6 are 2nd category and so on. here i want to place a 1 so that the 3rd category won't have a zero element. This is what i want to do briefly but with a whole matrix with all the categories.

so here the output will be =

```
     [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
      0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0;
      0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0;
      0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0;
      0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1]
```

This code was tried but it doesn't give the required output as the 1 was placed in the 1st row not in the place where it has to be (the category that it should be in).

```
sum_cols_B = sum(B);               % Sum of Matrix B (dim 1)      
[~, idx] = find(sum_cols_B == 0);  % Get indices where sum == 0

% Using loop to go through the indices (where sum = 0)          
for ii = idx  
B(1,ii) = 1;                       % Insert 1 in the first position of that 
end                                % column in Matrix B
```

Ask me if the question is still not clear.!

Comment: I don't understand where you want to place the 1's. I don't understand why one must be in row 4, and the other one in row 3 or 5. Why not row 4 for that one too? And what if there are three columns with zeros after each other?

Comment: because the 1's have to be placed in groups; columns 1, 2 and 3 are together, columns 4,5 and 6 are together and columns 7, 8 and 9 are together. so if the 1 is placed in 1 column of the group then it can't be placed in any other place.

Comment: @Sassosamer Right but are the 1's in random spots? It is not clear what determines where a 1 goes, you've only stated the condition of where they *can't* go

Comment: They can be placed in a column that belongs to the group of the columns in order to make the sum doesn't contain a zero

Comment: @Sassosamer yea that still doesn't answer anything. How do you define *which row* they are in

Comment: A row where the sum of all the rows together isn't greater than 1 and in each row the 1's are in the same group. If there is more than 1 row the 1 can be placed in, then it will be placed In the place of the higher number. Hope that helps

Comment: I forgot to clarify something that Matrix B I already have it and I want to upgrade it to become the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an updated loop that will add the missing 1's:

```
sum_cols_B = sum(B);
[~, idx] = find(sum_cols_B == 0);

group_size = 3;
for ii = idx 
   % Calculate the starting column of the group for column ii
   % There are (ii-1)/group_size groups
   % Add 1 for 1-based indexing
   group_start = floor((ii-1)/group_size)*group_size + 1;

   % Determine which rows in the current group have nonzero values
   group_mask = sum(B(:,group_start:group_start+group_size-1), 2) > 0;

   % Find the row number of the max in A column ii corresponding to mask
   [~,rownum] = max(A(:,ii).*group_mask);

   % The value in column ii of B should have a 1 inserted
   % at the row containing the max in A
   B(rownum,ii) = 1;
end
```

Results for `B` above are:

```
B =

   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1
```

Comment: I have a question here, how is it related to the A matrix?

Comment: No i mean the A will have to be related if there are 2 rows that will need to be compared then it will go to the higher number in Matrix A

Comment: Error using idivide>idivide_check (line 65)
At least one argument must belong to an integer class.

Error in idivide (line 41)
idivide_check(a,b);

Error in Test (line 30)
   group_start = idivide(ii, group_size)*3 + 1;

Comment: I don't understand it so can you please tell me how is the algorithm working? And how are you going to relate it to Matrix A?

Comment: Great job but i have a question. Don't you have any other way than the idivide thing or the uint32(3)?

Comment: A = [7 3 5 2 8 4 1 6;
     5 2 6 1 4 3 9 7;
     9 1 4 5 2 6 3 6;
     4 8 1 6 3 7 2 9;
     6 1 7 2 8 4 5 9]
B =  [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
      0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0;
      0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
      0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0;
      0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] I tried on this example with group size of 4 and it gave me an error

Comment: I missed a `-1`. Sometimes I hate 1-based indexing.

Comment: Where is this missing?

Comment: I've updated the code. It was missing in the division `floor((ii-1)/group_size)`.

Comment: Okay i got it! I am sorry but i have one last request, can you please tell me what does each line in the algorithm do?

Comment: Why did you add a +1 in the group start! you know i found out that the maximum part isn't working well

Comment: I know where is the problem. It is how we get the maximum. max1 = max(group_A, [], 2); This gives the maximum of the wrong column. It should get the maximum of the column that contains the zero.

Comment: we should add this a = group_A(:,c) where c is the number of the column. But i don't know how to get it

Comment: This is why you should clarify things in your question. Your comments are very hard to follow.

Answer (score 0):

```
B =  [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;...
      0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0;...
      0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0;...
      0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0;...
      0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1];          % Matrix - using this as an example

sum_cols_B = sum(B);               % Sum of Matrix B (dim 1)      
[~, idx] = find(sum_cols_B == 0);  % Get indices where sum == 0

% Using loop to go through the indices (where sum = 0)          
for ii = idx  
B(1,ii) = 1;                       % Insert 1 in the first position of that 
end                                % column in Matrix B
```

Comment: This is pretty unhelpful as it stands. Consider adding a more detailed explanation or some code.

Comment: Thanks Suever for the suggestion! I hope to update my response after Sasso samer clarifies the conditions for selecting where the 1's should go.

Comment: Matrix B is already predefined. What i want to do is reach the output.

Comment: @Sasso samer - please did you run the code below the matrix (B, just a copy of your matrix)?

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: @Sasso samer - copy and run the entire code and see if B is what you are looking for.

Comment: As in column 5 is this output, the 1 is put in another category than the category that it should be in. And we have to put into consideration Matrix A if we have more than  1 choice, as we will go for the highest.

Comment: @Sasso samer - do you mean the corresponding position where you have the maximum value in Matrix A? The output example you gave did not match this condition -- please clarify.

Comment: Yes exactly. Moreover the place of the 1 is the category is really important. Ask me again if you still didn't get the point

Comment: It is in the question      [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
      0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0;
      0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0;
      0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0;
      0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1]

Comment: @Sasso samer - Your output does not match your condition -- please check and update.

Comment: No it matches the conditions, the 1's are placed in the same category and when we had 2 choices, it went for the higher number. The sum isn't greater than 1.

Comment: For the categories part we can use ceil(indices/3)

Comment: @Suever I edited the question for more details. Thank you for your help

Comment: Let me simplify it if we have an array like this [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1] This array has 3 categories, columns 1,2 and 3 are 1st category, columns 4,5 and 6 are 2nd category and so on. here i want to place a 1 so that the 3rd category won't have a zero element. This is what i want to do briefly but with a whole matrix with all the categories.

Comment: Is it still not clear or what? tell me anything @Suever